# Javascript validation function always replying invalid

Tags: javascript, validation

I have done everything correct but still, for all values the function is display "Invalid" only. Can someone tell me where is the problem ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function alpha()
{ 
var x = document.getElementById('input1'); 
var y = x.value;
var z = isNaN(y);
if(z<1 || z>10){console.log("Invalid");} else {console.log("valid");}
}
</script>
</head>

<body> 
<button id="but1" onmouseover="alpha()" style="background:blue;">Click Me</button> 
<p id=para1> Hello! This is paragraph One! </p> 
<input type=text id=input1 > 
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for asking silly question! But, I cant find where code is getting wrong!

Comment: The returned value of  `isNaN`  is not a number but a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isNaN` returns a boolean and your comparing it to numbers. you'll want to compare `x` to your range.

```
if(z || x<1 || x>10)
```

Here is how I would clean up your code a bit

```
function alpha(){ 

    //name your variables something meaningful
    var userInputField = document.getElementById('input1');  

    //using parse int tells yourself and future programmers you want an int
    //it also gives you NaN if it's not a number so you don't have to check yourself
    //the 10 is the radix you want to convert to
    var userInputedValue = parseInt(x.value,10); 
    //check explicitly for NaN will save you some headaches
    if(userInputedValue === NaN || userInputedValue<1 || userInputedValue>10){
        console.log("Invalid");
    } else { 
         console.log("valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need `parseFloat` or `parseInt`. `x` is not a number but an element as well.

Comment: @zerkms while it is definitely better to use the correct type, wouldn't `x` be implicitly converted to a number when compared that way?

Comment: @t.niese if `x` is a number `isNaN(x)` would return false, since x is not not a number

Comment: @t.niese no worries. double negatives are always a pain